# Evaluate a and b. $\{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2: 2 \leq a \leq b \wedge a \times b = 15! \}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Evaluate an a and b:

$$
\| \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2: 2 \leq a \leq b \wedge a \times b = 15!  \}\|
$$

I figure out that it won't be possible to have a pair a and b such that $a \times b = 15!$, as in 15! there's a two primes 11 and 13 that won't generate a full square. However, probably I don't get the assignment correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate"? Find the number of such pairs? If so, count first the pairs $(a,b)$ with no restriction $a\le b$ and then divide by $2$ (as you correctly noted, $a=b$ is impossible). Hint how to count that: the number of such pairs is the number of divisors of $15!$, which is easy to find by considering its decomposition into primes.

Comment: $N^2$ means $N \times N$    nothing to do with squares

Comment: shouldn't a and b be a full squares?

Comment: @Shailesh thanks, now I got your point.

Comment: Great. Glad to help

Comment: the answer as easy: 2015, once I figure out what N^2 was ;)